# Pandora iPhone App URL Scheme parameters

Tags: iphone, pandora

Does anyone know if the Pandora iPhone app URL Scheme accepts parameters?

I am specifically interested in launching the app, with a new station based on an **artist name**.

I tried `pandora://artist/name` but I'm just guessing - does anyone have any info on this?

-

Much appreciated, Ran

Comment: You could send an email to the developer.

Answer (score 4):

This probably isn't quite what you're looking for, but it's the closest I've found.

```
pandorav2:/createStation?artist=Artist+Name
```

This will open the application to the New Station tab with the search results for the artist name you provided.

You can also launch directly into a station you have already created with:

```
pandorav2:/createStation?stationId=##################
```

Where the octothorpes should be the actual station ID. This can be found by going to your station in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 1):

When you're on Cocoppa just click the shortcut option & type in pandora.com/everywhere/mobile & that's gonna be the first link that's gonna pop up. Click & hold it & press "copy". Now go back to the "Edit Shortcut" page & paste that URL into the box where it creates the shortcut & you're good to go ! :)